# Javascript: dictionary method(property) mapping

Tags: javascript, methods

**tl;dr;** Is there a way to circumvent the cross browser implementations of functions by storing them in dictionary by same name?

I got this idea from this snippet:

```
    function styleThis ( element, styleType, styleTypeValue) { 
    // styleType, styleTypeValue must be strings
    element.style[styleType] = styleTypeValue; 
    }
```

So basic idea is like this :

```
    function _dasMethod ( element, method, methodValue){
    //method is String, methodValue is function stored in variable.
        element[method] = methodValue;
    }
```

The idea is to use `dictionary` style mapping to map specific methods according to the Browser type and input parameters.

So instead of :

```
function IE_ver8( element, argument1, argument 2 ... argument n ){
   element.property = some_IE_function(argument 1 ... argument n ); //
}
```

You could preload specific methods to elements before hand, and call them by their name:

```
function IE_check_size(){}
function CHROME_check_size(){}
function OPERA_check_size(){}  
    . . .  

function _dasMethod( element, MethodName, method_var ){
   element[MethodName] = method_var;
} 

//Which could be used like:  
If( Opera){ _dasMethod(div, "check_size", OPERA_check_size); }
If( Chrome){ _dasMethod(div, "check_size", CHROME_check_size); }
If( IE ){ _dasMethod(div, "check_size", E_check_size); }

div["check_size"](a,b,c,d);
```

Is there a way to implement similar action as `c++ preprocessor directives` in `javascript` for each element via some sort of `dictionary`?

I am using raw coding with no external libraries, so i would be grateful if you don't `opt-out` by recommending external library.